# LayoutInflater - inflate layout from XMLPullParser

Tags: android, xml, layout, xmlpullparser

I am trying to make a custom "layout builder", where some of the view tags (for instance relative layout) including all its children are removed from the XML file defining the layout based on some conditions (access permissions).

I have the main layout wrapper called wrapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I have for instance test.xml file defining the layout saved in /res/raw folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/section1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/section2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Lets say, that a specific user does not have access to the section one, so that one will be removed from the test.xml file.

XMLDocumentParser (responsible for parsing .xml file to Document):

```
public class XMLDocumentParser implements IXMLDocumentParser {

    @Override
    public Document getDomElement(Context context, int resource) {

        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try{
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = docBuilder.parse(context.getResources().openRawResource(resource), "UTF-8");
            //doc = docBuilder.parse(new BOMInputStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(resource), false, ByteOrderMark.UTF_8));

        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }
```

XML layout builder (responsible for removing the sections and creating XMLPullParser):

```
public class XMLLayoutBuilder implements IXMLLayoutBuilder {

    private IXMLDocumentParser documentParser;
    private Context context;

    public XMLLayoutBuilder(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        documentParser = new XMLDocumentParser();

    }

    @Override
    public XmlPullParser removeUnauthorizedSections(HashMap<String, String> permissions, int resource) {

        Document doc = documentParser.getDomElement(context, resource);

        Node rootNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList topLayouts = rootNode.getChildNodes();

        for(int i = 0; i < topLayouts.getLength(); i++){
            Node element = topLayouts.item(i);

            /*
            if(Check for permissions for specific layout and section){
                //Remove node with all its children
                rootNode.removeChild(element);
            }
            */
        }

        return getXMLPullParserFromString(getStringFromDocument(doc));
    }

    private String getStringFromDocument(Document doc)
    {
        try
        {
           DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
           StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
           StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
           TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
           Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
           transformer.transform(domSource, result);
           return writer.toString();
        }
        catch(TransformerException ex)
        {
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    private XmlPullParser getXMLPullParserFromString(String xml){

        if(xml == null) return null;

        XmlPullParser pullParser;

        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            pullParser = factory.newPullParser();
            pullParser.setInput(new StringReader(xml));

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
        return pullParser;
    }
```

MainActivity (should inflate the content of XMLPullParser to the root element of wrapper.xml layout):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button btn_login;
    private IHttpRequestProcessor processor;
    private ILayoutBuilder layoutBuilder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wrapper);

        layoutBuilder = new LayoutBuilder();

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_root);

        layoutBuilder.buildLayout(null, R.raw.test2, getApplicationContext(), ll);
}
}
```

LayoutBuilder:

```
public class LayoutBuilder implements ILayoutBuilder {

    private IXMLLayoutBuilder xmlLayoutBuilder;

    @Override
    public View buildLayout(HashMap<String, String> permissions, int resource, Context context, ViewGroup root) {

        xmlLayoutBuilder = new XMLLayoutBuilder(context);
        XmlPullParser xmlParser = xmlLayoutBuilder.removeUnauthorizedSections(permissions, resource);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(xmlParser, null);


        return null;
    }

}
```

When I run the app, I got this error:

```
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.managmentsystem/com.example.managmentsystem.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: START_TAG <LinearLayout {http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}android:layout_width='match_parent' {http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}android:layout_height='match_parent' {http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}android:orientation='vertical'>@1:216 in java.io.StringReader@52732da4: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: START_TAG <LinearLayout {http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}android:layout_width='match_parent' {http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}android:layout_height='match_parent' {http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}android:orientation='vertical'>@1:216 in java.io.StringReader@52732da4: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at layoutbuilder.LayoutBuilder.buildLayout(LayoutBuilder.java:23)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.example.managmentsystem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     ... 11 more
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     ... 21 more
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.util.XmlPullAttributes cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1366)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:416)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3317)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:459)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
11-03 12:23:38.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     ... 24 more
```

Comment: Your stack trace shows that the crash stems from a `LayoutBuilder` class, which you do not have in the question. Beyond that, I would think that it would be orders of magnitude faster to simply remove the affected views from a layout inflated normally, rather than attempt to write your own layout inflation engine.

Comment: I included the LayoutBuilder class. I was thinking about the same you suggested (remove the affected views from a layout inflated normally). But on the other hand, is not it a bad practice? Why to generate something and then remove it right after.However, if I dont manage to solve this issue, I will probably go for the way you suggested.

Comment: "Why to generate something and then remove it right after" -- because your resulting code will be orders of magnitude simpler to maintain, and the performance implications should be negligible.

Comment: LayoutInflater is not meant to be used with custom XML file or custom XML logic. From the docs : "it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime;"

Comment: Also check Resources.java in AOSP source code. It says "note that for now we only work with compiled XML files.
            To support generic XML files we will need to manually parse
            out the attributes from the XML file (applying type information
            contained in the resources and such)."